# Filter/grep some output only by certain column?

Tags: linux, grep

How can I filter some output only by certain column?

I need something like this:

```
tail -f logs/access_log | grep -v "200" --only-in-column=1
```

So I want to see only lines that don't have string '200' in first column.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

awk is probably the canonical tool for this kind of problem.

```
$ cat data
foo 200 bar
foo 200 baz
bar 4   baz

$ cat data | awk '$2 != 200 { print $0 }'
bar 4   baz
```

Comment: By the way, you can write the action as `{ print }` or even omit it entirely (just `awk '$2 != 200'`), since `print $0` is the default action.

Comment: Thanks, nice to learn something by answering someone else's question.

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
tail -f logs/access_log | grep -v '^200[[:blank:]]'
```

which excludes lines that begin with "200" followed by a space or a tab.

You can choose different delimiter sets depending on your needs.

```
tail -f logs/access_log | grep -v '^200[^[:alnum:]]'
```

which excludes lines that begin with "200" followed by any character other than alphabetic or numeric characters.